# Print JSON using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to print the following json as

> id=79 title=web+Infographics path=web-infographics.

I like to know how to print it in a generic manner.

```
 var obj = {"data" : [
   {
     "id": "79",
     "title": "Web+Infographics",
     "path" : "web-infographics"
   }]}
```

Comment: That's not JSON, that's a plain ol' javascript object - and this is not https://icanhazcode.com/ - so, your code request is probably going to be ignored

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.keys(obj.data[0]).map(k => `${k}=${obj.data[0][k]}`).join(' ')
```

Not sure how much it will help you since your example is rather simplistic.

Next time, please show what you tried yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
var id = obj.data[0].id;
var title = obj.data[0].title;
var path = obj.data[0].path;

var jsonPrint = "id=" + id + " title=" + title + " path=" + path
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> var obj = {"data" : [
   {
     "id": "79",
     "title": "Web+Infographics",
     "path" : "web-infographics"
   }]} 
> $.param(obj['data'][0])
< "id=79&title=Web%2BInfographics&path=web-infographics"
```

Note: I'm assuming you want to print as query params instead of having a space between each. If you want the space then use the answer by @Amadan

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map funtion like this

```js
$(function() {

  
var obj = {"data" : [
   {
     "id": "79",
     "title": "Web+Infographics",
     "path" : "web-infographics"
   }]} 

$('#app').append($.map(obj.data, function(item){
  return `"id"=${item.id} "title"=${item.title} "path"=${item.path}`
}));

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```